# jQuery: кроссбраузерная валидация email в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проверяю содержимое поля ввода на соответствие регулярному выражению:

```
$('#inputMail').blur(function() {
  var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
  if(($('#inputMail').val() != 0)&&(!pattern.test($('#inputMail').val()))) {
    alert('Вы ввели некорректный e-mail');
    $('#inputMail').focus();
  }
```

В Хроме и Опере отлично работает. В IE и Firefox - нет. Как сделать кроссбраузерно?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_email

Comment: К чему это? (((

Comment: К тому что есть родная валидация email в html.

Comment: мне не нужна родная валидация, мне нужна кроссбраузерная валидация средствами jquery

Comment: Рекомендую вам рассмотреть возможность использования готовой библиотеки [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). Ее поддерживает множество браузеров, там есть проверка и на валидность email адреса. Сэкономите кучу нервов и времени.

Comment: А что мешает запрещать через те же регулярки вводить пользователю неугодные символы? Вторую собаку, две точки подряд, не буквенные/циферные символы, и т.п.

Answer (score 5):

### Не используйте регулярные выражения для валидации адресов электронной почты

Для проверки валидности адреса электронной почты достаточно проверить, присутствует ли в строке символ `@` с другими символами по бокам **только один раз**:

```
let isValid = ($('#inputMail').val().match(/.+?\@.+/g) || []).length === 1;
```

Проверять эмеил более сложной регуляркой - плохая идея. Адрес электронной почты может содержать не только `[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]`, но и [невероятную тучу других символов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax). Есть [регулярные выражения, составленные по спецификации](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), но из-за своей длины и сложности они неподдерживаемые. Более того, ваша регулярка поставит в тупик пользователей ящиков `@i.ua`, `@test.longdomainname.ru` и многих других вариаций, ибо домены могут быть как длиной в один символ, так и в [253 символа](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax).

### Используйте `type=email` даже если важна кроссбраузерность

Как вам указал пользователь [@Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman), следует использовать `type=email`:

```
<input type="email" required>
```

Этот атрибут очень важен для мобильных устройств. При нажатии на это поле ввода у пользователя во многих мобильных браузерах изменится клавиатура, которая упростит им ввод адреса электронной почты. Вторая важная функция данного атрибута - какая-никакая проверка валидности эмеила. Событие `submit` не будет срабатывать, если браузер будет считать введенный эмеил невалидным. А неподдерживающие данное значение атрибута браузеры будут работать с полем как с `type=text`.

### Результат

Конечный результат должен выглядеть примерно так:

```js
$('#registration input[type=email]').on('blur', function () {
  let email = $(this).val();
  
  if (email.length > 0
  && (email.match(/.+?\@.+/g) || []).length !== 1) {
    console.log('invalid');
    alert('Вы ввели некорректный e-mail!');
  } else {
    console.log('valid');
    alert('Вы ввели корректный e-mail!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="registration">
  <input type="email" required>
</form>
```

JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/terron/4r8wyuop/](https://jsfiddle.net/terron/4r8wyuop/)

Comment: "присутствует ли в строке символ @ с другими символами по бокам только один раз" - ну вот, например, dfgjh@dfhg - это корректный адрес? очевидно, что нет. хотя символ @ с другими символами по бокам присутствует и только один раз. как минимум ещё на точку надо проверять. да и на длину домена верхнего уровня тоже было бы неплохо.

Comment: @humster_spb, да, [валидный](http://oi65.tinypic.com/2z8zzo9.jpg).

Comment: И длину домена верхнего уровня проверять не надо. С технической точки зрения они могут быть и длиной в один символ (но на данный момент минимальная доступная длина - 2 символа), так и в целое слово, например, `mitsubishi`. Их добавляют довольно активно и ограничивать длину домена первого уровня было бы глупо, потому что заранее не знаешь, какую могут добавить доменную зону.

Comment: ну, в смысле - валидный? на dfgjh@dfhg не придёт ни одно письмо, потому что это не адрес, а огрызок адреса. как минимум в конце ещё должна быть точка и домен верхнего уровня. в чём Вы меня пытаетесь убедить? )) в том, что это не надо проверять? -) я считаю, что надо обязательно - если есть желание получить именно e-mail, а не набор символов с @ посередине.

Comment: @humster_spb, вы мой скриншот-то смотрели? Откройте с Андроида, iOS или любого линукса `http://to/` и вы увидите чудо.

Comment: @humster_spb, а, не, даже в Windows открывается. Стоит лишь добавить домен нулевого уровня - точку: `http://to./`. В прочем, в Линуксе работает и без нее, по аналогии с `http://localhost/`.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вот это `$('#inputMail').val()` возвращает не 0 а пустой string.

```
$('#inputMail').blur(function() {
  var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
  if($(this).val() && !pattern.test($(this).val()) {
    alert('Вы ввели некорректный e-mail');
    $(this).focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: Не, ничего не изменилось. Думаю, что дело здесь в pattern.test($(this).val() - IE и Firefox не понимают, что это значит. Как-то по-другому написать проверку можно?